# How to remove "followers" text from Twitter Follow Button?

Tags: php, twitter

I have managed to make a twitter follow button work. The button shows with how many current followers a user has (i.e.: 34.3K followers). The question now is how can I remove the text "followers" from a twitter follow button?

I have used the below code to render the button:

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a href="http://twitter.com/twitterusername" class="twitter-follow-button" data-width="160px" data-show-screen-name="false" data-align="middle">Follow twitterusername</a>
```

Is there a way to remove the "followers" text by just giving the link a data-attribute? Any other solution would be helpful.

TIA

Eralph

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` to access the `iframe` (twitter button is using iframe to load data), and then insert the following CSS:

```
[id=follow-button] span.label { padding-left: 16px!important; }
[id=follow-button] [id=l] { display: none!important; }
```

Notice that the iframe is inserted into DOM dynamically, which means you have to wait for it been loaded.

Comment: You can't modify the iframe, that would violate cross domain access.